# Rx way to execute something in c sharp until a condition is true or timeout

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a list of job names in database table that can be started by calling an API with job name as parameter. Each of these job takes 10 to 30 mins to complete. There is another API that can be called at some interval(10 mins) to check the completion status of the job. A Job can be started only when previous job in the list has completed/timeout. What these jobs do is irrelevant here.

I am very much fan of Rx framework but have little knowledge of it.

I am currently fetching all the job names from db then looping through it 
in each cycle i am calling the Job-trigger API to start the job and then keep calling Job-status API at some interval until the job has completed or has timed out before the next job cycle starts.

```
foreach(string jobName in lstJobs)
{
 if(StartTheJob(jobName)) //if job successfully started
 {
    do{
        Task.Delay(10000);

    }
    While(GetJobCompletionStatus(jobName));
    // how to timeout this do/while loop
 }
}
```

The problem is, if the job keeps running for hours i am not finding a way to timeout the do while loop and trigger the next job. Is there a better way to do this using Rx?

Comment: Is there anyone who can save my life??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource):

```
foreach(string jobName in lstJobs)
{
 if(StartTheJob(jobName)) //if job successfully started
 {
    do{
        Task.Delay(10000);

    }
    While(!ct.IsCancellationRequested);
 }
}
```

You can create a `CancellationToken` using a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource):

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
var ct = cts.Token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do this with Rx:

```
IObservable<string> query =
    from jobName in lstJobs.ToObservable()
    from started in Observable.Start(() => StartTheJob(jobName))
    where started
    from done in
        Observable.Amb(
            Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30.0)).Select(_ => true),
            Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10.0))
                .SelectMany(_ => Observable.Start(() => GetJobCompletionStatus(jobName)))
                .Where(s => s))
    select jobName;
```

The logic here is that you're stepping through each of the jobs and calling `StartTheJob`. If it's successful then you are awaiting a `done` from either (i.e. `.Amb(...)`) the 30 minute `.Timer(...)` or the calls to `GetJobCompletionStatus` made every 10 minutes until a `true` is returned. Finally it returns the `jobName` so that you can see what was successful. When the observable completes you can compare to the original list to see if any were unsuccessful.

Comment: Unlike his example, doesn't this execute all jobs in parallel?

Comment: @Asti - Yes, you're right. I will have to rework. I'll get to it later when I'm back at my desk.